# Predicition of future batches in time series

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, time-series, forecasting

i am working with neural networks and i want to predict the time series further ahead. I did a course on neural networks where this kind of problem is faced. But i dont really understand how it works.

```
def model_forecast(model, series, window_size):
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(series)
    ds = ds.window(window_size, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
    ds = ds.flat_map(lambda w: w.batch(window_size))
    ds = ds.batch(32).prefetch(1)
    forecast = model.predict(ds)
    return forecast

rnn_forecast = model_forecast(model, x_valid[:, np.newaxis], window_size)
rnn_forecast = rnn_forecast[:, 0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))

ax.plot(time_valid, x_valid, 'k-', label='Validation data')
ax.plot(time_valid[window_size-1:], rnn_forecast, 'r-', label='RNN forecast')
ax.plot(time_train, x_train, 'b-', label='Training data')
ax.set(
    xlabel='Date',
    ylabel='Number of sunspots',
    title='Monthly averaged number of sunspots',
)
plt.legend()
```

This is the code and it is working fine. My question is why is the validation series needed in the forecast function? Isn't that the thing i want to predict? Or do i parse it in as the last known frame of the series? I thought that when training is done, i should only need the test_time and get the x_valid as output.